How to get the product attribute value from an attribute with Cyrillic characters in WooCommerce
I try to get product attribute's value and show it on single product page, but I don't understand, how to get attribute's value if it was created not in attributes section of WooCommerce, but was created custom only for this product.
For example.
I was created Brand attribute throw the WooCommerce attribute section. And now I use:
global $product;
$brand = $product->get_attribute('brand');
echo $brand;

It's work good!
But I have problem. I have added Sostav attribute for product on product's settings in variation section. Not throw the Woocommerce attribute section.
I try:
$sostav = $product->get_attribute('sostav');
But it's don't work.
As I understand, the reason is absence 'pa_' before this attribute.
I get all attributes using get_attributes and have seen, that Brand attribute - "pa_brand", but Sostav attribute - "sostav".
How can I get product attribute's value of my Sostav attribute for this product?


As you are using "Cоctaв" name, which has Cyrillic characters, you should try to use: $sostav = $product->get_attribute('Cоctaв');…
